# Showing MessageBox in long running process

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, callback, action

In an `MVVM` application I have a long running calculation that runs
in legacy code.

That legacy code shows a `MessageBox` to ask the user if it shall continue.

Now I want this code to stick to `MVVM` as easy as possible and thought
about handing in a callback to show the `MessageBox` and evaluating the
result inside.

How can this be done the easiest?

Have often seen Action for callbacks, but I have no idea how
to work with the bool inside the legacy code.

I want to pass the string to show in the `MessageBox` from the legacy code
and return the decision (a bool) to the legacy code.

Please note: I do not have to do a bigger refactoring right now, but want
to get rid of the `MessageBox` inside the legacy code right now.

Perhaps I can use a function like

```
    private bool ShowMessageBox(string text)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show(text, "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

        if (result.Equals(MessageBoxResult.Yes))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**-edit-**

Should I use some

```
Action<string, Action<bool>>
```

for the method signature?
How can I access the bool in the legacy code?

Comment: This reminds me of [Synchronization By Modal](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Synchronization-by-Modal.aspx)

Comment: @HighCore That is what I want to get rid of. If I use our animation for "doing some action" in the view this MessageBox gets blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a `delegate`?

For the method you showed, you can create a `delegate` like this:

```
public delegate bool ShowMessageBoxDelegate(string text);
```

Then let's say you have a property using the `delegate` as the type:

```
public ShowMessageBoxDelegate ShowMessageBoxDelegateProperty { get; set; }
```

Now if your `ShowMessageBox` method matches the signature of this `delegate`...

```
public bool ShowMessageBox(string text)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show(text, "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    if (result.Equals(MessageBoxResult.Yes))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

... then you could set it as the value of the `ShowMessageBoxDelegateProperty` property:

```
ShowMessageBoxDelegateProperty = ShowMessageBox;
```

Note the missing parenthesis. A `delegate` can also be multicast, which simply means that they can have more than one method attached to them:

```
ShowMessageBoxDelegateProperty += ShowMessageBox;
```

You can also use them as parameters in methods:

```
public void ProxyShowMessageBox(ShowMessageBoxDelegate showMessageBoxDelegate)
{
    if (showMessageBoxDelegate != null)
    {
        bool result = showMessageBoxDelegate("MessageBox message");
    }
}
```

You would then call it like this:

```
ProxyShowMessageBox(ShowMessageBox);
```

You can find out more from the [Delegates Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) page at MSDN.

Comment: Yes, I added a delegate. But I need to refactor that code. Thank you very much!